# How could I deal with a string variable in a DBSCAN?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dbscan

Today I'm working on a dataset from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data. I would like to try to use a DBSCAN which integrate bed, bath, neighborhood and price. The problem is that that I don't know how do deal with the string variable neighborhood, I tried to use dummies variable and that's not relevant with a lot of neighborhood. Is someone has an idea ? Many thanks in advance, do not hesitate to comment to have more information.

Comment: What about mapping it to a categorical integer?

Comment: Hi AKS, I tried with get_dummies but I get a bad result with my dbscan after when there are too many neighborhoods. Do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: I mean https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html